# Any products that can generate OpenAPI YAML from SpringMVC source or bytecode?

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, gradle, swagger, openapi

I have a large-ish application written in SpringMVC and Angular. Currently, I have an in-house library that generates Angular dataobjects and services based on an existing SpringMVC application. This generation happens at build/compile time using reflection to inspect java bytecode.

I would like to replace this in-house library with Swagger+OpenAPI because the in-house library is deficient in several ways.

My understanding is Swagger is a great tool to generate angular boilerplate, but works from OpenAPI YAML (and other text formats).

What is desired/required is the following workflow:

1. Write or modify some java/webmvc
2. At build time, generate the YAML OpenAPI spec FROM the java source or bytecode
3. At build time, generate the Angular dataobjects and services from the generated YAML.

I have found several product that will generate OpenAPI YAML from java, but only in a running appserver not from source or bytecode.

Are there any products which support this workflow in an efficient manner (preferably well integrated with Gradle)?